# vstest fails to load newtonsoft

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, vstest

I am trying to run the test cases using C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe.

But some test are failing with exception System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Stack Trace:
at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)

The same test cases are passing in visual studio ide (same version of vstest and IDE is used)

My project is using newtonsoft 12.0.3.

I am not able to understand why test are passing in IDE and failing in console.
I checked my project and found that same version of newtonsoft is being used which is 12.0.3.

Comment: It would really help if you could provide a [mcve]. (And these days, is there any reason you want to use vstest.console.exe rather than just "dotnet test" from the console?)

Comment: The error complains that the *wrong* library version is used. This isn't a VSTest problem. Most likely your test project references an older version. Use the Consolidate tab in NuGet Package Manager to ensure all projects in the solution use the same version

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The problem is only happening at vstest side. Thats why I suspect that something is missing at vstest side. Same test cases runs perfectly in visual studio 2019 IDE.I checked in consolidate tab and there is no package with different version.I am suspecting that it might be using some .net system library which is old but not sure about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating further I found the difference between running the test in Visual studio IDE and via console. Visual Studio IDE uses MSTest to run the test and vstest is the utility to run the test via console. Both have different configurations.
I found that MsTest has following

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.5.0.0-12.0.0.2" newVersion="12.0.0.2"/>
    <codeBase version="12.0.0.2" href="PrivateAssemblies\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Added the above in testhost.exe.config in vstest configuration and this
resolved the problem